# Change product url in woocommerce order detail

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Need help with shortcode or snippet. I want to change url of products in order detail in cms, now url redirects to edit product but I want do redirect to webshop product, any idea how to change url?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joHPP.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you there is no filter to change it ;)
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-item.php
line 13

Comment: Thank you, that really help! It fix my problem. 
I changed code and now link directs to product in shop and not to edit product.
Here's my code I changed 
`$product_link = $product ? get_permalink( $product->get_id() ) : '';`

Comment: Thing is, if you changed in in same file what I refering, this might be reverted back after WC update (it's in core files)

Comment: Thank you for info! For now WC update is disabled so am good, but yes, still need better solution.